# Report Viewer in 2010 with .Net 3.5 causing Error when compiled

Tags: reportviewer, report

I'm using Vs 2010 with .Net 3.5. I have windows project and using Report Viewer for reporting purpose. I designed reports using Report Viewer. It works fine on my machine but on deployment server, compiler gives the following error:

> The report definition is not valid.  Details: The report definition has an invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition'
>   which cannot be upgr
>          aded.

Please note that I have all of my report files as Content.

Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

Is VS2010 and .net 3.5 installed on your build server? And reportviewer?